# What's going on in following code? Can somebody explain each line please

Tags: c++, stl, dynamic-programming

Trying to solve the problem `Bytelandian gold coins` on the `spoj` and requirement is Dynamic Programming and I really want to understand and discuss the solution. primarily the `reference variable r`. Why here `map STL` is used? How `map` reduces the effort?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
unsigned Coin(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned & r = m[n];
    if(r)
        return r;
    unsigned s=(n/2)+(n/3)+(n/4);
    if(s>n)
        return r = Coin(n/2)+Coin(n/3)+Coin(n/4);
    return r = n;
}

int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    cout<<Coin(n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For efficiency, the reference ensures there's only one lookup in the map. Since `n` is never modified, you can replace `r` with `m[n]` throughout the function to see what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common idiom for recursion with *memoization*. The idea is that `Coin(n)` should be called at most once for each value of `n`. The first time it's called, we should compute the value and then store it somewhere, so that the second time it's called, we just return the stored value rather than doing the recursive computation all over again.

The map is used to store the previously computed values. You can't use an array, because it would be too big. An array uses space proportional to its largest index, whereas a map only uses space proportional to the number of key-value pairs it contains.

The reference is a cute trick. Once the `Coin` function is called with a particular value of `n`, there are two possibilities:

1. The value is already stored in the map, because we've already computed it
2. The value isn't already stored in the map, but it will be by the time we're done, because we always want to store a value as soon as we compute it, so we won't have to compute it a second time.

The line `unsigned & r = m[n];` initializes `r` to refer to the stored value, if there is one. If there isn't, then it *inserts* the key `n` into the map, then makes `r` a reference to the value. In the remainder of the body, we can just compute the answer and store it in `r`. This will *automatically* update the value stored in the map.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more with example n=12. It'll be really a great help.
Thanks

Comment: The first time `Coin(12)` is called, the line `unsigned & r = m[n]` sets `m[12]` to zero and makes `r` refer to that zero. Eventually, the correct value of `Coin(12)` is calculated and stored in `r`. Because `r` is a reference to `m[12]`, this will also set `m[12]` equal to that value.

The second time it's called, `r` will be initialized to refer to `m[12]`. This will be nonzero since it has already been computed, and the function will just return that value.

Answer (score 0):

it is a Dynamic Programming Problem, in case you don't know please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

The idea of Dynamic Programming is to cache the result, so that later exact call will finish in O(1)/O(lg n) time. but I doubt if this program is complete, I cannot find variable m (which is a set) declaration line.

The formula of this problem is
Coin(n) = max(max(n/2+n/3+n/4, Coin(n/2)+Coin(n/3)+Coin(n/4)), n)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
unsigned Coin(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned & r = m[n];             //see if the value is computed
    if(r)
        return r;                    //if computed, return the computed value.
    unsigned s=(n/2)+(n/3)+(n/4);    
                    //if not, find out the max profit for coin with r on it.
    if(s>n)
        return r = Coin(n/2)+Coin(n/3)+Coin(n/4);
                    //if conversion can make a profit, make the profit
                    //Coin(p) >= p => Coin(n/2)+Coin(n/3)+Coin(n/4) >=n/2+n/3+n/4

    return r = n;   //if not, do not do the conversion
}

int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    cout<<Coin(n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I doubt if(s>n) is needed. it may prune some good cases which s<n, but with later conversion Coin(n/2)+Coin(n/3)+Coin(n/4) > n